# Eclipse: Package Explorer file hightlight

Tags: eclipse

I am running Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0) on Debian 10.

I am wondering why some files in the Package Explorer (Java Project with Maven) are highlighted blue with a >. Having the dark theme enabled.

[image: ECLIPSE]

This files are not opened or special in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should mean that those files have been modified and not yet committed to your VCS (Git, Subversion, etc...).

Comment: I see it. Thanks!